# save error :unknown property 'DataInsert.fields'

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

Here is my apex class:

```
global class DataInsert {

     // property declarations

     Set<String> fields ; 

     global PageReference doInsert() {

        // other logic        

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Incident__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();       
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objSchema.fields.getMap();

        fields = new Set<String>();     
        for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){

            SObjectField sfield = fieldMap.get(fieldName);

            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
            if(objdlt.get(fieldName) == true) {
                if(dfield.isCustom() && String.valueOf(dfield.getSoapType()) == 'Boolean') {
                    system.debug(objdlt.get(fieldName));
                    fields.add(fieldName);
                    System.debug('All Fields are selected ::::'+fields);
                }  
            }
        }
```

This is my vf page :

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="DataInsert">
 <apex:form >

         <apex:pageBlock title="All Selected Fields ">        
           <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="key">            
                <apex:outputText value="{!key}"/> <br/>
           </apex:repeat>
         </apex:pageBlock>  

 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But I got this error:

> save error :unknown property 'DataInsert.fields'

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your page to be able to iterate the collection, you need to give it a public getter. One way to do so would be:

```
public Set<String> getFields() { return fields; }
```

However, I would hesitate to use a `Set` for this functionality, since the order would not be very predictable. A better method might be to alphabetically sort them:

```
public List<String> getFields()
{
    List<String> sortedFields = new List<String>(fields);
    sortedFields.sort();
    return sortedFields();
}
```

There is also a syntactic alternative to the above, which is similar to how you've declared your other properties:

```
public Set<String> fields { get; private set; }
```

If you change your declaration of the `fields` variable to the above, then it will become a *property* and be accessible by the page. Note that you do *not* need a public setter, and I use `private set` everywhere possible to clearly indicate properties which cannot be written by the page.

Comment: From this part i'm not getting the fields   <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="key">            
                <apex:outputText value="{!key}"/> <br/>
           </apex:repeat>

Comment: @venkat I know...you have to modify your controller. Did you try to make the suggested alterations to your code?